# Melhor maneira de modelar o banco de dados de um chat

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Tenho uma aplicação que trabalho com webServices e o banco mysql, estou colocando um chat nela, a parte de como pegar mensagens, exibir notificações e procurar usuários que já tenho, minha dúvida é:

**Como eu devo armazenar as mensagens no banco?**

Pensei em algumas formas, mas não acho interessante. 
A primeira foi, criaria uma tabela mensagens no meu banco e nela teria remetente, destinatário e a mensagem, mas não acredito ser interessante, pois as mensagens podem ocupar muito espaço no meu banco.
A segunda foi, não usaria meu banco externo, e sim o SQLite, nele eu salvaria o histórico das conversas, assim cada usuário teria apenas suas mensagens em seu banco. Mas isso não posso fazer, pois se meu usuário logar na sua conta em outro aparelho, as mensagens não estariam lá.

Comment: Talvez um armazenamento total no dispositivo e manter na nuvem apenas as últimas 10 ou 20 mensagens...

Comment: Mas qual a razão de não querer armazenar no MySQL? Não compreendi isso.

Answer (score -1):

Uma outra solução seria você utilizar o Dropbox. Se caso o usuário desejasse ter histórico de mensagem o mesmo poderia efetuar o login através do Dropbox e daí, você teria acesso a salvar arquivos na conta dele através da API do Dropbox. Sendo assim, você não ocuparia espaço na sua base de dados :D